# How to make subcategory for the items located in vector list in java

Tags: java, vector, collections

I am making a java program which requires making a list which will be added in the vector class using `vector.add()` method. And then I want to make a subcategory for the list items which is located in vector list. Like this.

`1. Drink
    a> Soda
    b> Tea
    c) Cofee
2. Grocery
    a> Item1
    b> Item2
    c) Item3`

Drink and Grocery will be added to the vector list. Now how can I manage the subcategory list? Can we use `Collection` for this? If yes, then how?

`**Please provide a useful method to tackle this problem** Thanks`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a class, for example with name `Category`, which contains category and list of items which belongs to this category.

```
class Category {
    String category;
    List<String> items;
    ...
}
```

Now create list of categories using Vector

```
Collection<Category> categories = new Vector<Category>();
```

Sample code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Create a vector of categories
        Collection<Category> categories = new Vector<Category>();
        // Create drinks
        List<String> drinks = Arrays.asList("Soda", "Tea", "Cofee");
        // Add drinks to vector
        categories.add(new Category("Drink", drinks));
        // Create groceries
        List<String> groceries = Arrays.asList("Item1", "Item2", "Item3");
        // Add groceries to vector
        categories.add(new Category("Grocery", groceries));

    }

}

class Category {
    String category;
    List<String> items;
    public Category(String category, List<String> items) {
        if (category == null || items == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Category and items cannot be null");
        }
        this.category = category;
        this.items = items;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But how to insert the data into it. And how can I get each item as well as their category? I am sorry I am not good at collections.

Comment: I would strongly advise you to go through Java Collections framework first. However, I updated answer with code, please check.

Comment: Thanks! It's really helpful.

Comment: I just have got a problem. Now I want to print the main category in JList1, and the subcategory in JList2. But I am unable to retrieve them. How can I retrieve them?

Comment: Please share your code, I cannot help you with this information